# How to process the messages in order(one by one) using JMS: Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a scenario like below,

Inbound Queue called 'InQ'(Synchronous) which will have messages each with  messageHeader `JMSXGroupID`(Example A or B Or C).Based on the `JMSXGroupId` header i will route to clientA or ClientB or ClientC.

SomeTime If ClientA takes longer Time to respond. I don't want to take the otherMessages in Queue `InQ' which have`JMSXGroupID=A`.Once the response is back, i need to process the other messages in Order.

I did implemented `Client Ack Transaction`.But in this cases if i'm waiting for the response from ClientA, other messages with `JMXGroupId B and C` also seems to be waiting.Which means it looking by overall one by one(FIFO) which i don't want to do.

Not sure how to implement FIFO based on JMSXGroupID. Any thoughts and Ideas will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" username="....." password="..." brokerURL="...." validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"  numberOfConsumers="1"  maxRedelivery="-1" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" persistentDelivery="true"/>

     <flow name="testFlow">
    <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="InQ" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <jms:client-ack-transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>          
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="**testCheck#[payload]"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.JMSXGroupId=='A']">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="***first***"/>
            <flow-ref name="ClientA" doc:name="ClientA"/>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.JMSXGroupId=='B']">
            <flow-ref name="ClientB" doc:name="ClientB"/>
        </when>
       <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.JMSXGroupId=='C']">
            <flow-ref name="ClientC" doc:name="ClientC"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger level="INFO"  doc:name=" Other Logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>     
</flow>
```

Edit1: Made all the 3 , listening to the same Queue.

```
     <composite-source doc:name="Composite Source">
     <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="InQ">
     <jms:selector expression="JMSXGroupID=A"/>
     </jms:inbound-endpoint>
     <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="InQ">
     <jms:selector expression="JMSXGroupID=B"/>
     </jms:inbound-endpoint>
      <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" queue="InQ">
      <jms:selector expression="JMSXGroupID=C"/>
      </jms:inbound-endpoint>
    </composite-source>
```

It does thrown the error `There is already a listener registered on this connector on endpointUri: jms://InQ`.

Comment: is it possible to build three listeners? A listener with selector JMSXGroupId=='A', B listener with selector JMSXGroupId=='B', and so on.

Comment: @BlitheHuang : Thanks for you response.As per existing design ,  we cannt  increase JMS listener  as per each client that the requirement unfortunately. Hence all the messages are pushed in to sameQ. Will it be possible by the above design?.Is there any way i have achieve ordering as per client header or something. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't express my self clearly. My point is that to create  3 listeners(consumers) listen to one queue. it may be like this in concept. http://timjansen.github.io/jarfiller/guide/jms/selectors.xhtml

Comment: Sorry for late Response. I did tried, please check the `edit1`. Got an error  "There is already a listener registered on this connector on endpointUri: jms://testInQ" . Reason is in the same config.xml we cannot add 3 queues in which all are listening to the same  queue.

Comment: @Blithe Huang: You you have any other thoughts, let me know will try. Thanks.

Comment: How about use "topic"?